# Looping through list items with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this block of code

```
listItems = $("#productList").find("li");

        for (var li in listItems) {
            var product = $(li);
            var productid = product.children(".productId").val();
            var productPrice = product.find(".productPrice").val();
            var productMSRP = product.find(".productMSRP").val();

            totalItemsHidden.val(parseInt(totalItemsHidden.val(), 10) + 1);
            subtotalHidden.val(parseFloat(subtotalHidden.val()) + parseFloat(productMSRP));
            savingsHidden.val(parseFloat(savingsHidden.val()) + parseFloat(productMSRP - productPrice));
            totalHidden.val(parseFloat(totalHidden.val()) + parseFloat(productPrice));

        }
```

and I'm not getting the desired results - totalItems is coming out as 180+ and the rest all NaN. I suspect its where i use `var product = $(li);` or perhaps with the expression on the loop itself. Either way - I need to loop through the `<li>` items in the `<ul>` labelled `#productList`

Comment: Do your "accumulator" fields start out with empty values?  If so, that's where your `NaN` results are coming from.

Comment: The reason you're getting 180+ items, is that a `for/in` includes prototyped properties, as well as properties of the actual instance. All of the jQuery methods that can be called against a jQuery object are part of the object's prototype. As you now know, `.each()` is a common way to iterate, though not the only way.

Comment: .each will do this. A working example http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/Hb28u/16/

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but this was answered 2 years ago...

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You need to use [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
var listItems = $("#productList li");
listItems.each(function(idx, li) {
    var product = $(li);

    // and the rest of your code
});
```

This is the correct way to loop through a jQuery selection.

---

In modern Javascript you can also use a [`for .. of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop:

```
var listItems = $("#productList li");
for (let li of listItems) {
    let product = $(li);
}
```

Be aware, however, that older browsers will not support this syntax, and you may well be better off with the jQuery syntax above.

Comment: just to add to this you probably want to change your selector to $("#productList li") as well. Rather than using find.

Comment: @Yads Not necessarily. I don't know for certain, but there's every chance that the original code will be more efficient in many browsers, as it doesn't require parsing the string so intensively.

Comment: Hmm, I did a few quick benchmarks in jQuery 1.4.2. Using the find method was about 30% slower than the aggregate selector on both IE7 and Chrome.

Comment: @Yads Fair enough then -- thanks for the information. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 19):

You can use `each` for this:

```
$('#productList li').each(function(i, li) {
  var $product = $(li);  
  // your code goes here
});
```

That being said - are you sure you want to be updating the values to be +1 each time? Couldn't you just find the count and then set the values based on that?

Comment: There is no need to pass i and li as arguments is there? Maybe I am missing something, but I thought the object being acted upon was passed by default to the function as the this object.

Comment: It never hurts to be explicit, though - I've been bitten a few too many times by relying on `this`. :)

Comment: @exoboy you're correct, but it's *also* true that jQuery passes as arguments the element and the element's index in the selected jQuery list.

Comment: @all: That's why I like this forum... it is nice to see other viewpoints and occasionally learn something new along the way.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
listItems = $("#productList").find("li").each(function(){
   var product = $(this);
   // rest of code.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For a more definitive answer, you'll need to post some of your markup. You can simplify your jQuery quite a bit, like the following:

```
$("#productList li").each(function() {
    var product = $(this);
    var productid = $(".productId", product).val();
    var productPrice = $(".productPrice", product).val();
    var productMSRP = $(".productMSRP", product).val();

    // the rest remains unchanged
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't do `$(".productId", $(this))` since it's just a less efficient way of doing `product.find(".productId")`. Also, you cached `$(this)` but never used it.

Comment: Ah, good points. I rarely bother to assign `$(this)` to another variable, but did so to keep the OP's code similar.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. By using the parent>child selector "#productList li" it should find all li elements. Then, you can iterate through the result object using the each() method which will only alter li elements that have been found.

```
listItems = $("#productList li").each(function(){

        var product = $(this);
        var productid = product.children(".productId").val();
        var productPrice = product.find(".productPrice").val();
        var productMSRP = product.find(".productMSRP").val();

        totalItemsHidden.val(parseInt(totalItemsHidden.val(), 10) + 1);
        subtotalHidden.val(parseFloat(subtotalHidden.val()) + parseFloat(productMSRP));
        savingsHidden.val(parseFloat(savingsHidden.val()) + parseFloat(productMSRP - productPrice));
        totalHidden.val(parseFloat(totalHidden.val()) + parseFloat(productPrice));

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this without jQuery `.each()` you'd have to fix your code like this:

```
var listItems = $("#productList").find("li");
var ind, len, product;

for ( ind = 0, len = listItems.length; ind < len; ind++ ) {
    product = $(listItems[ind]);

    // ...
}
```

Bugs in your original code:

1. `for ... in` will also loop through all inherited properties; i.e. you will also get a list of all functions that are defined by jQuery.
2. The loop variable `li` is not the list item, but the *index* to the list item. In that case the index is a normal array index (i.e. an integer)

Basically you are save to use `.each()` as it is more comfortable, but espacially when you are looping bigger arrays the code in this answer will be much faster.

For other alternatives to `.each()` you can check out this performance comparison:
http://jsperf.com/browser-diet-jquery-each-vs-for-loop

Comment: Why just not to reduce for-loop like (and remove len variable at all): for ( ind = 0; ind < listItems.length;  ind++ ) {

Answer (score -1):

```
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $("form").submit(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
       var name = $("#name").val();
       var amount =$("#number").val();
       var gst=(amount)*(0.18);
           gst=Math.round(gst);

       var total=parseInt(amount)+parseInt(gst);
       $(".myTable tbody").append("<tr><td></td><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+amount+"</td><td>"+gst+"</td><td>"+total+"</td></tr>");
       $("#name").val('');
       $("#number").val('');

       $(".myTable").find("tbody").find("tr").each(function(i){
       $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first-child').text(i+1);

       });

       $("#formdata").on('submit', '.myTable', function () {

                   var sum = 0;

          $(".myTable tbody tr").each(function () {
                    var getvalue = $(this).val();
                    if ($.isNumeric(getvalue))
                     {
                        sum += parseFloat(getvalue);
                     }                  
                     });

                     $(".total").text(sum);
        });

    });
   });

   </script>

     <style>
           #formdata{
                      float:left;
                      width:400px;
                    }

     </style>
  </head>


  <body>  

       <form id="formdata">  

                           <span>Product Name</span>
                           <input type="text" id="name">
                            <br>

                           <span>Product Amount</span>
                           <input type="text" id="number">
                           <br>
                           <br>
                           <center><button type="submit" class="adddata">Add</button></center>
       </form>
       <br>
       <br>

      <table class="myTable" border="1px" width="300px">
      <thead><th>s.no</th><th>Name</th><th>Amount</th><th>Gst</th><th>NetTotal</th></thead>

      <tbody></tbody>

      <tfoot>
             <tr>
                 <td></td>
                 <td></td>
                 <td></td>
                 <td class="total"></td>
                 <td class="total"></td>
             </tr>

      </tfoot>
      </table>

   </body>
```