# How can i search ordered list using the "each" function in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do this loop using jquery but I can't do it.

### This is my code

```js
this.isFound = function (li, text){
  for(var i = 0; i<li.length; i++){
    if(li[i].innerHTML == text){
      this.showError("Sorry, You can't enter a string twice");
      return true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return false;
};
```

### This is my JQuery loop

```js
$.each(this.list, function(i, item){
  if(this.text == item.innerHTML){
    return true;
  }
});
```

**How can I do that using each or grep or any function else in JQuery?!**
thanks in advance

Comment: and why you want it into each.. for loop is not bad. Also, $.each is for iterating over object whereas you are trying to iterate over list

Comment: `$("[someSelector] li").each(...)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping through list items with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511652/looping-through-list-items-with-jquery)

Comment: I the script that you wrote it.
my question is 
how can I check an innerHTML of an element in the list inside each 
when I write something like that 
`if(li.innerHTML == text)`
the innerHTML append the previous values not one value like here in the for loop

Comment: _"the innerHTML append the previous values not one value like here in the for loop"_ Can you include that description at Question? Do you mean all of the previous `.innerHTML` values that have been iterated?

Comment: yes I want one value to check if it equals like the for loop and I tried and searched many sites and references and can't do it.

Comment: @MohamedKamel Requirement at Question is not presently clear. What do you mean by _"the innerHTML append the previous values not one value like here in the for loop"_? Is expected result a single match, or multiple matches? Is expected result an array or a jQuery object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.grep()` to return an array of matches, or `.filter()` to return a jQuery collection of elements, where the return value of the callback should be `Boolean` `true` or `false`

`$.grep()`

```js
$(function() {
  var text = "abc";
  var res = $.grep($("li"), function(el, index) {
    return el.textContent === text
  });
  // `res` is an array containing one or more `DOM` elements
  console.log(res);
  res[0].style.color = "red";
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul>
  <li>abc</li>
  <li>def</li>
  <li>ghi</li>
</ul>
```

`.filter()`

```js
$(function() {
  var text = "def";
  var res = $("li").filter(function(index, el) {
    return el.textContent === text
  });
  // `res` is a jQuery object containing one or more `DOM` elements
  // where jQuery methods can be chained
  console.log(res);
  res.css("color", "green");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul>
  <li>abc</li>
  <li>def</li>
  <li>ghi</li>
</ul>
```

If you are trying to determine if a given element has `.textContent`, and if `true` do stuff, you can use `.is()`, which returns a `Boolean`; either `true` or `false`

```js
$(function() {
  var text = "ghi";
  var i = 0;
  var res = $("li").is(function(index, el) {
    i = index;
    return el.textContent === text
  });
  // `res` is a `Boolean`
  console.log(res);
  if (res) {
    alert(text + " has already been set");
    $("li").eq(i).css("color", "gold");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul>
  <li>abc</li>
  <li>def</li>
  <li>ghi</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
I appreciate this.